# how to position images as a grid

Tags: tables, columns

I am using the code below to position images

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p!]
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\setkeys{Gin}{height=0.1\textheight,width=0.1\textheight} 

\caption{[Something Descriptive for Method 1]} % provide a suitable caption
\bigskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} r @{} *{2}{M{0.1\textheight}} @{}}
& Method 1 & Residual \\
\llap{Image 1\quad} & \includegraphics{fig1a} & \includegraphics{fig1b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 2\quad} & \includegraphics{fig2a} & \includegraphics{fig2b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 3\quad} & \includegraphics{fig3a} & \includegraphics{fig3b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 4\quad} & \includegraphics{fig4a} & \includegraphics{fig4b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 5\quad} & \includegraphics{fig5a} & \includegraphics{fig5b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 6\quad} & \includegraphics{fig6a} & \includegraphics{fig6b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 7\quad} & \includegraphics{fig7a} & \includegraphics{fig7b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 8\quad} & \includegraphics{fig8a} & \includegraphics{fig8b} 
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but i have 16 images, as 16 images cannot fit in a single page which makes them so small. so i want to poition the rest of the 8 images as a side column. need help to do this

Need to do similar to this:
[image]

Comment: What does a "side column" mean?

Comment: side column mean i have updated my question with the picture how i need

Comment: In the middle i need the names of the pictures like Image 8, Image 9 ... I am mentioning here because this is missed in the picture i have kept above

Comment: So you just need an extra column (or two) where you can insert more images...

Comment: yes, I need extra column, The problem i am facing is they are decreasing the size when i add more columns. The size should not decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

With use `tabularray` and `adjustbox` packages it is simple: just declare white table lines, push images baselines to their vertical center and add two more columns to table:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[demo,               % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\adjustboxset{height=0.1\textheight,width=0.1\textheight,valign=c}

\caption{Something Descriptive for Method 1 and Method 2} % provide a suitable caption
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={r cc cc}, colsep=3pt, rowsep=3pt,
             vline{4}={1em,white},
              }
        & Method 1                & Residual   
        & Method 2                & Residual            \\
Image 1 & \adjustimage{}{fig1a} & \adjustimage{}{fig1b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig1c} & \adjustimage{}{fig1d} \\
Image 2 & \adjustimage{}{fig2a} & \adjustimage{}{fig2b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig2c} & \adjustimage{}{fig2d} \\
Image 3 & \adjustimage{}{fig3a} & \adjustimage{}{fig3b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig3c} & \adjustimage{}{fig3d} \\
Image 4 & \adjustimage{}{fig4a} & \adjustimage{}{fig4b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig4c} & \adjustimage{}{fig4d} \\
Image 5 & \adjustimage{}{fig5a} & \adjustimage{}{fig5b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig5c} & \adjustimage{}{fig5d} \\
Image 6 & \adjustimage{}{fig6a} & \adjustimage{}{fig6b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig6c} & \adjustimage{}{fig6d} \\
Image 7 & \adjustimage{}{fig7a} & \adjustimage{}{fig7b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig7c} & \adjustimage{}{fig7d} \\
Image 8 & \adjustimage{}{fig8a} & \adjustimage{}{fig8b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig8c} & \adjustimage{}{fig8d} \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: while using `\usepackage{tabularray}` i am facing problem i am getting`file tabularray.sty not found` in overleaf. how to rectify this error

Comment: @harsha, package seems to be too new for Overleaf. I'm not familiar with Overleaf, but there is probably possibilities, that you load it to folder with your document. Ask their staff, how to do this or search this site or goggle ("how to add package to Overleaf")

Comment: can we do this without using `\usepackage{tabularray}` package ?

Comment: @harsha, you can do this, of course. But code will be probably less elegant.

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded .sty file for tabularray but i didn't know how to connect it to overleaf. after uploading it to my overleaf how to attach to my main document

Comment: @harsha, I wrote new answer which use simple `tabular` package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127940/discussion-between-harsha-and-zarko).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibilities is use simple `tabular` package and add `margin` option to `\adjustboxset`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo,               % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\adjustboxset{height=0.1\textheight,width=0.1\textheight,
              margin=0pt 6pt 0pt 6pt, valign=c}

\caption{Something Descriptive for Method 1 and Method 2} % provide a suitable caption
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{r cc @{\qquad}cc}
        & Method 1                & Residual
        & Method 2                & Residual            \\
Image 1 & \adjustimage{}{fig1a} & \adjustimage{}{fig1b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig1c} & \adjustimage{}{fig1d} \\
Image 2 & \adjustimage{}{fig2a} & \adjustimage{}{fig2b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig2c} & \adjustimage{}{fig2d} \\
Image 3 & \adjustimage{}{fig3a} & \adjustimage{}{fig3b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig3c} & \adjustimage{}{fig3d} \\
Image 4 & \adjustimage{}{fig4a} & \adjustimage{}{fig4b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig4c} & \adjustimage{}{fig4d} \\
Image 5 & \adjustimage{}{fig5a} & \adjustimage{}{fig5b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig5c} & \adjustimage{}{fig5d} \\
Image 6 & \adjustimage{}{fig6a} & \adjustimage{}{fig6b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig6c} & \adjustimage{}{fig6d} \\
Image 7 & \adjustimage{}{fig7a} & \adjustimage{}{fig7b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig7c} & \adjustimage{}{fig7d} \\
Image 8 & \adjustimage{}{fig8a} & \adjustimage{}{fig8b}
        & \adjustimage{}{fig8c} & \adjustimage{}{fig8d} \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result is similar as you get with solution in the my first answer.