# I was unable to decrease the distance between the columns

Tags: overleaf

I was trying to adjust the grid of image and I am getting extra distance between the images and I was unable to decrease no matter what I have done.

```
\restoregeometry
\newgeometry{ a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=10mm,}


    \begin{figure}[p]
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\adjustboxset{height=0.114\textheight,width=0.114\textheight,valign=c}

\caption{Something Descriptive for Method 1 and Method 2} % provide a suitable caption

\begin{tblr}{colspec={r cc r cc}, colsep=2pt, rowsep=1pt,
             vline{4}={2em,white},
              }
        & Method 1                & Residual   &
        & Method 2                & Residual            \\
I32 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Pr10
        & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pr10-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pr10-MAE+KL+ranger21_noisy.png} \\
        
I43 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I43-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I43-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Pr20
        & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} \\
        
I66 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I66-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I66-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Pr30
        & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} \\
        
I87 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I87-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I87-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Pr40
        & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} \\
        
Pg10 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg10-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg10-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Ps1
        & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} \\
        
Pg20 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg20-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg20-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Ps05
        & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} \\
        
Pg30 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg30-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg30-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Ps025
        & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/I32-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} \\
        
Pg40 & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg40-MAE+KL+ranger21.png} & \adjustimage{}{resultimg/Pg40-MAE+KL+ranger21_noise.png} & Pgt
        & \adjustimage{}{} & \adjustimage{}{} \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

when I tried to use this code using a demo sample image on other latex file its fine as shown in the figure
[image]

It may be effected by the previous settings. how can I modify the code so that it won't take the grid spacing settings from the rest of the latex document.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Is this related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606588/how-to-position-images-as-a-grid ?